# Need help finding a unique value in array

Tags: c, arrays, search

My code is complete minus one little flaw.  It searches the array and prints out which values are unique, however it always counts the first entry as unique even if it is followed by the same value.  Can anyone look at my code and tell me which part is messing this up because it is driving me crazy.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define size 7
    int main(void)
    {
        int array1[size], target, answer, found, x, k, prev, count =1, i;

        printf("Please input %d integers: ", size);
        scanf("%d", &target);

        for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
             scanf("%d", &array1[x]);

        }

        prev = array1[0];

        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) 
        {
             if (array1[i] == prev) 
             {
                 count++;
             } 
             else 
             {
                 if (count < 2)
                     printf("%d=%d\n", prev, count);
                 prev = array1[i];
                 count = 1;
             }

        }

        if (count < 2)
        {
             printf("%d=%d\n", prev, count);
        }

        return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Consider sorting your array, that way you'll only need to scan it once to find duplicates/unique values.

Comment: Sorting also allows for binary search - and this will speed things up a bit.

Comment: I may just be reading this incorrectly (its late and I'm too sleepy to be doing this :) ), but I'm not entirely sure you're getting the entire array's value frequency checked here.

Comment: Another approach might be to simply set up an array of ints, say freq[x], and iterate through your array1 one time, incrementing freq[array1[x]]++. That gives you a complete frequency table, and all you need to do is find the indices for freq[] where its value is 1.

Comment: I would start over with the code. It's a little hard to read..but its late here.

Comment: new to C, how would I go about sorting the array

Comment: @bardockyo: `qsort(array1, size, sizeof(*array1), cmp_int);`
`cmp_int` is your comparison function of the form: 
`int cmp_int (const void *a, const void *b)`.

It should basically return `*(int*)a - *(int*)b`. Check the man pages for `qsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your code though, but the error is obvious. For example, if the input array is `9 8 7 9 8 7 9`, the `prev` should be 9 at first iteration and when `i == 1`, `prev == array1[i]` is false. And we come to the else clause, of course the `count` is only `1` now. I suggest you rewrite the whole things... Either build a array to store the frequency of each entry, or sort the array.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.  I know the code is clunky.  I am still very new to C.

Comment: @bardockyo That's ok. I suggest read more good examples in C.

Comment: @bardockyo If that did fix your problem then you should accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Okay, couldn't resist the temptation to just post this stub to maintain a distinct frequency count.

```
int countFreq(int data[])
{
   int freq[size];

   for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
   { 
      freq[data[x]]++;
   }

   for(int y=0; y<size; y++)
   {
      if (freq[y]==1)
        printf("Unique value: %i",y);
   }
}
```